# How to call my ITEM from the FIREBASE DATABASE? Please

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

In principle, I have a database created in Firebase whose database is connected to the project (Android Studio). I have an Item called "urlmovie" which contains a URL for a movie.

How do I call that Item that contains that URL (it is uploaded in the Firebase database) I want that when I click on the play button it will launch the movie.

This is my **MOVIES_ACTIVITY.JAVA** Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

ExtendedFloatingActionButton extendedFloatingActionButton =findViewById(R.id.fab);
extendedFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String peliculaName = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        String url="";
        switch (peliculaName) {
            case "BAD BOYS FOR LIFE (2020)":
                url = "IF I PLACE THE URL HERE, PLAY THE FILM BUT I DON'T WANT THE URL TO BE PLACED FROM THE PROJECT IF IT IS ALREADY IN THE DATABASE (FIREBASE FROM GOOGLE)";
               break;
            case "SCOOBY! (2020)":
                url = "";
                break;
            case "BIRDS OF PREY (2020)":
                url = "";
                break;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), player.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", url);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**PLAYER.JAVA**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

//VARIABLES
playerView = findViewById(R.id.plaver_view);
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

//FULLSCREEN
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//VIDEO URL
Uri videoUrl= Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
```

[click here to see the image (DATABASE FIREBASE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh2h8.png)

Comment: I need help, it's a job from the University...